# Team member showing off other's work

Tags: professionalism, colleagues

One of my friends work in a good firm in an MNC. He is hard working and sharp guy. He seems to love the work he is doing but he always complains about somethings which I can not properly answer.

One of his teammates who is also hard working, intelligent always tend to be apple of eye of upper management. He chats one-to-one with Product Management about new features being developed by some one else in team.

Some of his irritating things are:
- Giving demo my friend's work to product manager
- Scheduling one to one meeting with Support team to explain how to debug issues in an area my friend is mostly focussed to.

Not to mention, there are other things too being done by him without informing my friend. I believe this is against professionalism.

Upper management likes him very much because he works very hard and works 12-13 hours a day.

I am not sure if this is right thing. Is he thinking too much ?
Should I advice him to talk to his manager about this ?

Comment: Yes he is very active in talking to product management... He is also involved in all the issues especially in his area... Yes he schedule demos for what he works on and mostly it happens in sprint end... About the amount of work I think he gives nearly 8-9 hours which is less than his coworker....

Comment: Does your friend object to the co-worker doing these things?  Or is he perhaps grateful that the co-worker is relieving him of management-related stuff so he can get on with work?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like he's trying to take on more of a management role. Your friend may view him as a peer but that may not be how he sees himself. Would your friend prefer that he wasn't given a managerial role? This person who took your friends idea seems to be trying to join enough swim lanes that I would expect a middle or upper level manager to play that role. This behavior seems as though it could be indicative of a company that's understaffed.

Your friend should decide if he wants to move up or out. If he wants to move up then this guy could be trying very hard to block him.

Comment: I don't think the company is understaffed. As per my conversation with my friend, everyone in the team knows that he is the best person to demo/present on that particular topic given his experience with issues he has handled and since he implemented that feature, how justified is this on that person's behalf to schedule a meeting and that too without informing my friend.

Comment: In my opinion I would judge this fair if that person has included my friend in that meeting atleast and I think he deserves to be informed that something like is about to happen. What do you think ?

Comment: Your friend is probably right about his subject matter expertise. Is there a manager or team lead who is supposed to communicate new features to other teams? It could be confusing for a team to have multiple representatives.

Comment: Actually, Product Management define all new features and all of them are presented once done at the end of sprint in which it was completed..

Comment: If your friend approached the other guy as a mentor then the other guy may have felt more comfortable including your friend in the meeting. What do you think?

Comment: Is there a team lead who presents the features to project management?

Comment: No, both of them are peers So there is no mentor as such. Moreover, my friend was involved in the project for more than an year ago when this person joined the team. No, there is no team lead and you are responsible for showing your own work. This is what I know and rest i have to ask

Comment: Oh okay. Do you think they're competing for the dominant position where we would expect a team lead to emerge? Project management probably just wants the work done. It seems confusing to get parts of a story from multiple people